# What's the difference between `tf.random_normal` and `tf.random_normal_initializer`?

Tags: variables, random, tensorflow, initialization

Using the two functions seems to get the same result.

```
t4 = tf.get_variable('t4', initializer=tf.random_normal((2,), seed=0))
t5 = tf.get_variable('t5', shape=(2,), initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=0))
```

And I find inside the `random_normal_initializer()` also use the `random_normal()`.

I indistinctly realize the difference between them. The `random_normal` will return a constant tensor, but the `random_normal_initializer` will return value after init.

I want to know more about how to use of these two functions at the right time.

Does it use `random_normal` to init a variable will actually init twice(after init the variable)? In other words, if there performance problems between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maxim's answer to this question is excellent, but I want to answer a slightly more simple question (with a few examples) that the OP might be asking:

**Most basic answer**: `tf.random_normal` is a `Tensor`; but`tf.random_normal_initializer` is a `RandomNormal`, **not** a `Tensor`.  I think simple code best clarifies the difference between these two:

```py
# Simple examples to clarify tf.random_normal from tf.random_normal_initializer
tf.reset_default_graph()
# OP's code
t4 = tf.get_variable('t4', initializer=tf.random_normal((2,), seed=0))
t5 = tf.get_variable('t5', shape=(2,), initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=0))
# clarifying Tensor vs Initializer outside the context of get_variable.
t6 = tf.random_normal((2,),seed=0)
t7 = tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=0)
# types
print(type(t6)) # <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
print(type(t7)) # <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops.RandomNormal'>
# run the graph...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # OP's code
    print(sess.run(t4)) #[-0.39915761  2.10443926]
    print(sess.run(t5)) #[-0.39915761  2.10443926]
    # tf.random_normal is a Tensor
    print(sess.run(t6)) #[-0.39915761  2.10443926]
    # tf.random_normal_initializer returns a tf.RandomNormal, not a Tensor or Op, so can't be sess.run()!
    try:
        print(sess.run(t7)) # Exception!
    except:
        print("Exception!")
    # But notice that you don't need to initialize an initializer, just a variable.
    t8 = tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=0)
    t9 = tf.get_variable('t9',shape=(2,), initializer=t8)
    sess.run(t9.initializer)  # still need to initialize the variable
    print(sess.run(t9)) #[-0.39915761  2.10443926]
```

**In your setting**: Now, as far as the code you are calling goes, there is no real difference; the `initializer` keyword is overloaded to accept both and will behave as Maxim indicates.  From [the tf/ops/variable_scope docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py):

```py
if initializer is None:
          init, initializing_from_value = self._get_default_initializer(
              name=name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype)
          if initializing_from_value:
            init_shape = None
          else:
            init_shape = var_shape
        elif callable(initializer):
          init = initializer
          init_shape = var_shape
        elif isinstance(initializer, ops.Tensor):
          init = array_ops.slice(initializer, var_offset, var_shape)
          # Use the dtype of the given tensor.
          dtype = init.dtype.base_dtype
          init_shape = None
        else:
          init = ops.convert_to_tensor(initializer, dtype=dtype)
          init = array_ops.slice(init, var_offset, var_shape)
          init_shape = None
```

Answer (score 4):

[`tf.random_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal) returns a *tensor* of the specified shape filled with random normal values. In addition, it creates a number of under-the-hood ops to compute the value:

```
random_normal/shape
random_normal/mean
random_normal/stddev
random_normal/RandomStandardNormal
random_normal/mul
```

At runtime, consecutive evaluations of this tensor produce a new value, but not other nodes are added.

---

[`tf.random_normal_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal_initializer) is an `Initializer` *instance*, which invokes `tf.random_normal` upon calling. So there is no big difference between `tf.random_normal_initializer` and `tf.random_normal`. Even if you call the init twice, neither of those will add new nodes to the graph. But both add 6 additional nodes in compilation.

---

Another alternative (that may be even more efficient in some cases) is initialization with `numpy.random.normal` array, like this:

```
t1 = tf.Variable(name='t1', initial_value=np.random.normal(size=(2,)))
```

<strike>This way no `random_normal` nodes are added to the graph, neither in compilation or in runtime.</strike>

**UPD**: tensorflow adds the const op `.../initial_value` in this case and the whole numpy array is going to be present in the graph, which may be a problem if the array is large.

Comment: Note that the third alternative, using `numpy.random.normal()`, will be inefficient if the size is large, because it will add a large *constant* to the graph whose size is proportional to the product of the array dimensions. The `tf.random_uniform()`/`tf.random_uniform_initializer()` approach uses constant space in the graph. (Since the initializer typically runs only once at the start of training, the runtime impact is negligible in either case.)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't check it in tensorboard, but I didn't notice any additional nodes in `tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()` - I was looking specifically if there's a const op there. Is it `initial_value`?

Comment: Yep, I think it would be the tensor named "<var name>/initial_value:0", created [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/25d275280dfb163674f81c7681c2c1d34545a155/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L335).